# Ctrl arrow keys not working in tmux inside VirtualBox

Tags: server, tmux

I am running a Ubuntu Server 16.10 inside a Virtualbox 5.1.20. In tmux, I am unable to resize the panes using the prefix Ctrl-Up, Ctrl-Down, Ctrl-Left and Ctrl-Right commands. I know the Ctrl key itself is working because the tmux prefix (Ctrl-b) is working fine but when I click on Ctrl-Up it seems to ignore the Ctrl and execute only arrow up (switch panes) command. Moreover, it seems to be a problem with Ubuntu Server because the same commands are working fine in Ubuntu Terminal.

Comment: You can try if this works for you: https://askubuntu.com/a/634338/3940